# Getting Singleton Warning in prolog (denomination change)

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I was writing a prolog predicate to print possible changes for given value,
on running it shows a warning that `X2` is a singleton variable. `X` is the given value, `T` is given List of available denominations and `L` is the resulting List.

*e.g*: `change(100,[1,2,5,10],L).`

```
change(X,T,L) :-
    change1(X,T,[],L).
change1(X,[H|T],AC,L):-
    X > 0,
    X >= H,
    X2 is X-1,
    change1(X2,T,[H|AC],L);
    change1(X2,[H|T],[H|AC],L);
    change1(X,T,AC,L).
change1(0,_,AC,AC).
change1(X,[],_,_):-X \= 0,false.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a *singleton* warning because the comma `,` has higher precedence than `;`, so the effective grouping of your code is:

```
change1(X,[H|T],AC,L):-
    (   X > 0,
        X >= H,
        X2 is X-1,
        change1(X2,T,[H|AC],L)
    )
    ;   change1(X2,[H|T],[H|AC],L)
    ;   change1(X,T,AC,L).
```

(note the parentheses) which isolates `change1(X2,[H|T],[H|AC],L)` from any queries that might instantiate `X2`. So `X2` is singleton in that context. You probably meant:

```
change1(X,[H|T],AC,L):-
    X > 0,
    X >= H,
    X2 is X-1,
    (   change1(X2,T,[H|AC],L)
    ;   change1(X2,[H|T],[H|AC],L)
    ;   change1(X,T,AC,L)
    ).
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!

```
:- use_module([library(clpfd),library(lists)]).
:- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_anon, false).
```

We define `change_/4` like this:

```
change_(Total, Units, Amounts, Zs) :-
   same_length(Units, Amounts),
   Units   ins 1..sup,
   Amounts ins 0..sup,
   scalar_product(Units, Amounts, #=, Total),
   append( [Total|Units],Amounts, Zs).
```

Sample query:

```
?- change_(100, [1,2,5,10], Amounts, _Zs), labeling([], _Zs).
  Amounts = [0,0,0,10]
; Amounts = [0,0,2,9]
; Amounts = [0,0,4,8]
...
```

Comment: Any reason to write `clpfd;`?

Comment: Beautiful. How did you put all the links to web document reference for each function? I assume not by hand... some prolog involved? :P

Comment: @DiegoSevilla.  I made it with my bare hands:) Building the right "automagic" sure is on my list. OTOH I'm still figuring out what I actually want... say, what a *decent* number of links is... Right now, I think it would be best to have *at most* one link per predicate in my current view: Make believe I'm having five `(ins)/2` goals within my view. Then only the first should be a link, the other ones better remain plain. That way the number of visible links would be more even when zooming out... What's your stance on this?

Comment: Yes, that is good. I noticed that. It is nice and not too intrusive, but it makes you think, for example, that the second ins is different of the first, so you have to read it twice to see if there is some small spelling difference (say ins, lns), that may got uncaught to a first review of the code. Still I liked it :)

Comment: @DiegoSevilla. I get that but I believe these problems can by and large be avoided by using the right practises. Like avoiding extremes (w.r.t. links, highlighting, etc.). Or like *always* including "real" code and "real" answers---"real" in the sense that some [tag:prolog-toplevel] has had contact with it at least once:)